# How to avoid 307 on rest GET call

Tags: jquery, rest

I am making a GET call but it's changing url of request, because of which I am getting wrong url in code behind using HTTP CONTEXT (in real using SPContext...), Looking at network tag I got this,

Request URL : https://myPortal.govment.com/us/216/files/_vti_bin/project/project.svc/Users/ExistsByLuck?username=asdasdadasd

Location     : 
https://myPortal.govment.com/_vti_bin/project/project.svc/Users/ExistsByLuck?username=asdasdadasd

it's removing this "`us/216/files/`" from my url and `status code is 307  Temporary Redirect`

**How can I avoid this behavior ?**

This is how I am making this request,

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/project/project.svc/Users/ExistsByLuck",
    type: "GET",
    data: { username: parameterUsername },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding "/" to my calling url,

so now it looks like this,

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/project/project.svc/Users/ExistsByLuck/",
    type: "GET",
    data: { username: parameterUsername },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
```

[This helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358178/wcf-rest-error-http-307)